# jQuery reference to the form that triggered the call

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post

I am working with `jQuery` and `$.post()`.

I have the following code:

```
$('#form #buttonQuery').click(function () {
    var post = $.post(url, info,process, 'json');
}
```

From within the function, how can I refer to the form's `action` or `name`?

I tried `$(this).action`, but it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: You should have only unique IDs on the page.  You only need `$('#buttonQuery')…` If you have more than one element with the same ID, then you're doing something wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any form element has a built in native reference to the form, it's `this.form`

```
$('#buttonQuery').on('click', function () {

    var action = $(this.form).attr('action'); // jQuery

    var name = this.form.name; // native property

    var post = $.post(url, info, process, 'json');
});
```

In jQuery you could also do `$(this).closest('form');`